# How to pass parameter from a link to jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks on the link i need the JQuery method to fire, and call a web service, which is located at `/Project/Send/SendMethod`. When i click on the `send` link the method gets fired, i know this because the alert is getting displayed. But the problem is how to call the webservice. It would be good if it's a `POST` method.

```
<a href='' id='2' class='send'> Send  </a>
```

Jquery method

```
   $(function () {
        $('.send').click(function () {
            alert(this.id);

        });
    });
```

Comment: You'll need to read up on [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and try it out on a local server yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.ajax()` method and specify the url and options like this  [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.send').click(function (e) {
        e.prevenDefault();
       $.ajax({
          url: "Project/Send/SendMethod",
          type: "POST",
          data: values,
          success: function(){
                  alert("success");
                  $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: So if i replace `test.php` with `/Project/Send/SendMethod` should it work ? I tried but it doesn't call that webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `$.post`:

```
 $(function () {
    $('.send').click(function () {
        alert(this.id);
        $.post(url, {'id':this.id}, function (response) {
            //do the result oriented activities
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget `event.prevenDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `$.ajax()` api in jQuery. Moreover, you have to preventDefault the default behavior in your link. Otherwise, you will change page instead of sending ajax requset.

```
$('.send').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
        url:"Project/Send/SendMethod",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "id": this.id },
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.8+, since "success" callback is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. You should use the "done" http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

```
$('.send').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
        url:"Project/Send/SendMethod",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "id": this.id }
    }).done(function( data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery's `ajax()` functionality (and regularly do).

The example below assumes you're going to get a JSON-formatted response. You can change this if you're going to get back a full HTML page... take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more info.

```
$(function () {
    $('.send').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(thisId);
        var hostAndPort = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port; // current page and protocol (http or https)
        var requestUrl = hostAndPort + "/Project/Send/SendMethod/";
        var str_address = requestUrl + 'id?=' + thisId;
        $.ajax({
            url: str_address,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                // do something...
            },
            error: function (e) {
                // handle error
            }
        });
    });
});
```